# Is omlette better for the heart than a boiled egg?

Tags: diet, nutrition, eggs, cholesterol, heart

As per [this](http://www.livestrong.com/article/534651-does-egg-yolk-give-you-high-cholesterol/) article, the egg yolk (yellow) contains substantial amount of cholesterol while the white contains an insignificant amount of cholesterol.

When we prepare omlette, I believe some amount of cholesterol must be evaporating due to the intense heat. There is also a possibility that it will chemically react resulting in reduction of cholesterol. However in a boiled egg the cholesterol remains constant.
These are just my speculations and I would love to read some scientific proof validating whether my assumptions are true or false.

Now my question is that, if you have to consume the entire egg, which of these options is better for our heart and thus for our health?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either or my friend. Makes no difference. The cholesterol in eggs will cause you zero harm. This is a myth. In fact, it will likely help you. Read this article.

Why Egg Yolks Are Good For You: The Perfect Protein Source
by Poliquin™ Editorial Staff
11/5/2013 12:16:49 PM

Eggs are the perfect source of protein. They score highest on four scientific scales for protein quality! Not only do they provide an abundance of easily digested amino acids, eggs are packed with vitamins and nutrients that improve brain health and aid in fat loss.

For example, choline, which is supplied in the egg yolk, is essential for brain function because it is needed for the body to make a critical neurotransmitter called acetylcholine.  In addition, choline helps the liver to detoxify and avoid accumulating fat, which is essential for optimal liver function. Eggs also contain other nutrients such as the B vitamins, and two nutrients that may help prevent cancer: lutein and zeaxanthin.

Meanwhile, research shows there is no link between eating whole eggs and elevated cholesterol. In fact, if you eat as much as three eggs a day on a carbohydrate-restricted diet, you may decrease inflammation and improve cholesterol markers. That’s what happened to a group of men who had only 18 percent of their diet from carbs but ate fat liberally, including three eggs daily for 12 weeks. The men also lost 5 kg over the course of the study.

Take away the understanding that eggs are an excellent protein source that can be included in a low-carb, high-protein diet for optimal body composition and health. The key is to restrict carbohydrates, eat high-quality whole protein, and avoid processed or isolated fats.

Reference

Ratliff, J., et al. Eggs Modulate the Inflammatory Response To Carbohydrate Restricted Diets in Overweight Men. Nutrition and Metabolism. 2008. 5(6).
© 2013 Po